# Renaming file and changing the extension

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory with almost 2000 images and some of them don't have the right extension. And these extensions are formatted like this `*.images(xxx) 1`. Is it possible to change the extension to `jpg`

**UPDATE**
I have this code but it omits the extension.

```
declare -i i=0;
for f in *;
    do
        fn=$i".${f##*.jpg}";
        mv "$f" "/home/vianney/Desktop/IPIP/$fn";
        i=$((i+1));
    done
clear
```

How could I change this code to display the filetype

Comment: There are commands called `rename` and `prename` that may be available on your machine — one or both.  Try `prename --help` and `rename --help` and see what to do.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *
do mv "${i}" "${i%.*}.jpg"
done
```

To expand a bit on the issues addressed in the comments below; here is a variation on the program which appends a sequential numerical suffix to the files as they are processed:

```
#!/bin/sh

count=0
for i in *.*
do mv "${i}" "${i%.*}.${count}.jpg"
   count=$((count + 1))
done
```

Comment: How could I possibly tweak it to change the extension `.images (num)` Thanks

Comment: Like somefile.images or somefile.images999?

Comment: It already changes the extension using the shell's parameter expansion substring processing operator `%` like ${var%pattern}.

Comment: and I want the file name to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n-1. Also sir. There is an error in the code. The error is `mv: cannot stat ‘*’: No such file or directory
`

Comment: I added a variation to the code above based on what I perceive to be your criteria. Let me know how it works.

Comment: Sir. I found the error. My directory is empty. Lol. :D

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `mv` and bash oneliner:
`for file in *.images*; do mv "$file" "${file/\.*/\.jpg}"; done;`

Let me know if it helped you?

Comment: How could I tweak it so that the filename would be sequential? 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-1

Comment: Try this: `n=1; for file in *.images*; do mv "$file" "${file/\.*/$n\.jpg}"; n=$((n+1)); done;`

Comment: Unfortunately not sir. It just copies the files to another folder. I posted an update above. Thank you. :D

Comment: Well, I did test, created some files and named them as you described. That loop renamed that files like this `somename1.jpg`. If it doesn't work, then paste list of files you have, or list of files you get after running that script.